# More efficient way for this script?

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm fully aware that this is the ***wrong*** way of doing it, but I'm not really that familiar with ruby. I'm pretty sure the best option would be to use case? or a loop?

```
def addInfoToStory(idOfStory, storyTitle, storyPriority, storyEST, storySupporter, storyBugzilla, storyStatus, storyOutcome, storyCustomer, storyNotes)
  @browser.div(:id => "#{idOfStory}"+"_firstCol").div(:class => "tDetEntry", :index =>1).div.double_click
  @browser.div(:id => "#{idOfStory}"+"_firstCol").div(:class => "tDetEntry", :index =>1).div(:class => "formLib1").text_field(:id, 'input').set"#{storyTitle}"
  @browser.send_keys :tab

  @browser.div(:id => "#{idOfStory}"+"_firstCol").div(:class => "tDetEntry", :index =>2).div.double_click
  @browser.div(:id => "#{idOfStory}"+"_firstCol").div(:class => "tDetEntry", :index =>2).div(:class => "formLib1").text_field(:id, 'input').set"#{storyPriority}"
  @browser.send_keys :tab

  @browser.div(:id => "#{idOfStory}"+"_firstCol").div(:class => "tDetEntry", :index =>3).div.double_click
  @browser.div(:id => "#{idOfStory}"+"_firstCol").div(:class => "tDetEntry", :index =>3).div(:class => "formLib1").text_field(:id, 'input').set"#{storyEST}"
  @browser.send_keys :tab

  @browser.div(:id => "#{idOfStory}"+"_firstCol").div(:class => "tDetEntry", :index =>4).div.double_click
  @browser.div(:id => "#{idOfStory}"+"_firstCol").div(:class => "tDetEntry", :index =>4).div(:class => "formLib1").text_field(:id, 'input').set"#{storySupporter}"


  @browser.div(:id => "#{idOfStory}"+"_firstCol").div(:class => "tDetEntry", :index =>5).div.double_click
  @browser.div(:id => "#{idOfStory}"+"_firstCol").div(:class => "tDetEntry", :index =>5).div(:class => "formLib1").text_field(:id, 'input').set"#{storyBugzilla}"
  @browser.send_keys :tab

  @browser.div(:id => "#{idOfStory}"+"_firstCol").div(:class => "tDetEntry", :index =>6).div.double_click
  @browser.div(:id => "#{idOfStory}"+"_firstCol").div(:class => "tDetEntry", :index =>6).div(:class => "formLib1").text_field(:id, 'input').set"#{storyStatus}"
  @browser.send_keys :tab

  @browser.div(:id => "#{idOfStory}"+"_firstCol").div(:class => "tDetEntry", :index =>7).div.double_click
  @browser.div(:id => "#{idOfStory}"+"_firstCol").div(:class => "tDetEntry", :index =>7).div(:class => "formLib1").text_field(:id, 'input').set"#{storyOutcome}"
  @browser.send_keys :tab

  @browser.div(:id => "#{idOfStory}"+"_firstCol").div(:class => "tDetEntry", :index =>8).div.double_click
  @browser.div(:id => "#{idOfStory}"+"_firstCol").div(:class => "tDetEntry", :index =>8).div(:class => "formLib1").text_field(:id, 'input').set"#{storyCustomer}"
  @browser.send_keys :tab

  @browser.div(:id => "#{idOfStory}"+"_firstCol").div(:class => "tDetEntry", :index =>9).div.double_click
  @browser.div(:id => "#{idOfStory}"+"_firstCol").div(:class => "tDetEntry", :index =>9).div(:class => "formLib1").text_field(:id, 'input').set"#{storyNotes}"
  @browser.send_keys :tab
end
```

Any suggestions on the most efficient way I could do this process of filling out a form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
def addInfoToStory(idOfStory, *stories)
  stories.each.with_index do |story, i|
    @browser.div(id: "#{idOfStory}_firstCol").div(class: "tDetEntry", index: i+1).div.double_click
    @browser.div(id: "#{idOfStory}_firstCol").div(class: "tDetEntry", index: i+1).div(class: "formLib1").text_field(:id, "input").set(story)
    @browser.send_keys(:tab) unless i == 3
  end
end
```

Comment: Not exactly. There's no `send_keys` line at index=4. Not sure if it's intentional or a copy/paste error.

Comment: @sawa thank you, but do I list the stories array as the which story the string is entered in to, with story being the array of which strings are?

Comment: @samayres1992 Sorry, I couldn't parse your comment above. Can you rephrase it? Answers related to what I guess you may be asking is: (1) Local variables are only valid within this method definition, so it does not matter what names they are given. (2) The splat "*" turns the remaining arguments into an array.

Comment: @sawa, I'm horrible at explaining things hah.  for the information being entered, do I use story or *stories?

Comment: @samayres1992 As I wrote in the code above, you put `*stories` in the argument parameters to store the arguments in an array called `stories`. It does not matter what name you use as long as you call it withe the same name. Then, within the scope of `each.with_index`, you receive each element of that array as the variable `story`. Again, it does not matter what name you use. It is a Ruby convention (but not a syntax rule) to use a plural for an array and a singular for its element.

Comment: @sawa Thank you so much for the help, I'm just having a slight issue with the way that the information is being entered.  Each input requires a different input, so in ruby terms a string needs to be entered then the browser must tab to confirm the entry of the string, then move on to the next one.  But currently the code enters in all the strings in the same input, then tabs.  Any idea? Timing issues maybe?

Comment: I dont know what tabbing, sorry.

Comment: @sawa tabbing on the keyboard is this:  @browser.send_keys(:tab)